# Are levels 864 and 865 on Farm Heroes duplicates?

Tags: technical-issues, farm-heroes

When I go to screenshots like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6BXNSBFmwI), I see some player presenting how they got through 864.

Similarly one can say the same about level 865 [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZ8oUyBvrYA).

However when I played on king.com, my 864 looked like 865.  I successfully passed 864 and surprise I got to play the level all over again as 865.

Is this a know bug?  If so, what happened?  Was the game originally presented as the screenshot links I gave and then later changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I have received a King Care message asking me to check against the screenshots once again and now the issue seems resolved.  It is odd how another poster at the site had the same identical problem and then it all of the sudden shows up as fixed.  Oh well, however the issue resolves itself is fine with me, but now I see the correct behavior.

Comment: You can mark your answer as accepted so people will know that this question has been resolved :)

Comment: Ok I will mark it as such when the system allows me.